# Proper way to call a MYSQL stored procedure using Loopback4

Tags: loopback4

I'm trying to use Loopback 4 (https://loopback.io), what is the proper way to call a stored procedure and get the returned results? Do I create a repository or model (for the returned data)? Or should I do everything inside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple, I called mysql stored procedures directly from controllers.

```
import {Request, RestBindings, get, ResponseObject, getModelSchemaRef} from '@loopback/rest';
import {inject} from '@loopback/context';
import {param} from '@loopback/openapi-v3';
import {Product} from '../models';

const mysql = require('mysql');
const db = require('mysql-promise')();
const mysqlCreds = require('../datasources/retaildb.datasource.json');

export class V1Controller {
  private connection: any;

constructor(@inject(RestBindings.Http.REQUEST) private req: Request) {
  db.configure(mysqlCreds, mysql);
  this.connection = db;
}

@get('/search', {
  responses: {
    '200': {
      description: 'Search for Products using keyword(s)',
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: {type: 'array', items: getModelSchemaRef(Product)},
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
async search(@param.query.string('key') key: string): Promise<Product> {
  const sqlStmt = mysql.format('CALL PRODUCTSEARCH(?)', [key]);

  return new Promise<Product>(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.query(sqlStmt, function(err: any, results: any) {
      if (err !== null) return reject(err);
      resolve(results[0]);
    });
  });
}
```

In this example, retaildb.datasource.json is just a json file containing mysql connection settings:

```
{
  "name": "retaildb",
  "connector": "mysql",
  "url": "",
  "host": "ec2-x-x-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
  "port": 3306,
  "user": "root",
  "password": "mysqlpassword",
  "database": "retail"
}
```

And Product is the usual loopback model file, corresponding to what is returned by the stored procedure PRODUCTSEARCH in mysql:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `ProductSearch`(IN `searchkey` varchar(120))
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Product WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST (searchkey IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
END
```